# Sublime Text: commit local changes to remote folder the git way

Tags: git, synchronization, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sftp

I use SFTP plugin, which does not seem to accomplish what I'm looking for. It has an option to upload on save or by clicking on upload, however some files in my app are updated indirectly, for example via `gulp` script merging.

Also if I map `local > remote` after I have finished editing and testing my app locally, the mapping seems to go through entire project and see which files have been updated, my project is large so it takes forever and sometimes crushes.

Is there any plugins or methods which would allow me to sync local and remote folder and commit only the changes I have made since last commit?

Answer (score 1):

Using Git bash, you can manually add files you have changed and commit them.
Alternatively you can use a GUI app like [Github for Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), it will check your entire repo for changes but it uses timestamp so it takes no time at all.